# How to Tell if it is it a "ASP.NET Web Site" or an "ASP.NET Web Application Project"?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

If you are looking at the source of a project, in other words, a project already made, how can you tell if a project is a "ASP.NET WEB SITE" OR A "ASP.NET WEB APPLICATION PROJECT"?

It has already been asked here, I know, about the difference when you are trying to decide which type to create and what the benefits of each is.  But what if you have inherited the project that is already made.  What sort of tell-tale things tell you which type of project it is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you find a `Project file` within your `Solution` such as `.csproj` or `.vbproj`, it is a Web Application Project. Else, its a Web Site

Comment: Well.... I'll be.  You are right.  I created two projects and opened the windows explorer.  Sure enough, one does not have a .csproj file ad the other one does.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways:

Do you see any project files, if not, it's probably a web site.

Look and see if you have designer files in addition to your ASPX, and code behind pages. If they are present, then it's a web application project.

Look at the compiled site, and look at the bin directory. If you see lots of oddly named dlls then it's probably a web site. If you see only a couple dlls that could be names of projects, then it's a web application project.

Right-click on your website, or project, in VS and choose properties. You will see alot more options for a web application project than you will for a website such as options for Package and publish options, build events, and signing your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how to open the project because there's no solution file, then it's a Web Site.

If you opened the solution, and there's a web project, if it has a References node then it's a Web Application, if not it's a Web Site.